# I am trying to create a form using a table for the inputs

Tags: javascript, html

As I say, I am using a table to create a form. input-small and its label fits great in various places. I have opened up three rows in one column to place a 3 row textarea. Simple I thought, but I get a messed up table that appears OK in the live view but has half the input-small placeholders are missing, in the design view (Dreamweaver)it is full of broken tags.
Here is the code without the textarea and with.

Without

```
    <table width="581" border="0" summary="Contact">
  <caption>
    Personal Details
  </caption>
  <tr>
    <td width="120">Full Name</td>
    <td width="226"><input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder=".input-small"></td>
    <td width="71">Phone</td>
    <td width="146"><input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder=".input-small"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Postal Address</td>
    <td rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder=".input-small"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Emergency Contact</td>
    <td rowspan="2"><input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder=".input-small"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Postcode</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With

```
    <table width="581" border="0" summary="Contact">
  <caption>
    Personal Details
  </caption>
  <tr>
    <td width="120">Full Name</td>
    <td width="226"><input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder=".input-small"></td>
    <td width="71">Phone</td>
    <td width="146"><input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder=".input-small"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Postal Address</td>
    <td rowspan="4"><textarea rows="3" class="input-xxlarge" placeholder=".input-xxlarge"></td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder=".input-small"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Emergency Contact</td>
    <td rowspan="2"><input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder=".input-small"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Postcode</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Cheers

Comment: Don't trust in dreamweaver. It can be confused. Trust in the writed code. Your code works fine or your only problem is the "broken tags" in dreamweaver?

Comment: You have 2 options here, you can check the answers, I think they will fix your problem. Or my recommendation, use Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/ it makes it so much easier to do this kind of things. It also can be changed to fit you template needs by just editing or adding CSS rules onto your Style file

Comment: I like much more Foundation than Bootstrap, :P

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the textarea is not closed:

```
<td rowspan="4"><textarea rows="3" class="input-xxlarge" placeholder=".input-xxlarge"></textarea></td>
```

See `</textarea>`. It is needed.

Comment: Thank you for that. It seems obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

Close off the field with `</textarea>`:

`<textarea rows="3" class="input-xxlarge" placeholder=".input-xxlarge"></textarea>`